# Why I can't center this form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

```
<h2 class="mt-4 ml-4">{% trans "Contact Me" %}</h2>
<form method="post">
<div class="container mt-4">
    {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        {% trans "Subject" %}
        {% render_field form.subject class+="form-control" %}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        E-mail
        {% render_field form.email type="email" class+="form-control" %}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
           {% trans "Message" %}
        {% render_field form.message class+="form-control" rows="4" cols="6" %}
   </div>
   <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 ml-3">{% trans "Send" %}</button>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

if i do this:

```
form {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:200px;
}
```

or

```
form {
        margin: auto;
        width:600px;
}
```

I get this:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Don't look on it: dlfjklgljdfsg kdffg fdjgl hfgdg, hfsdfgh kldfhhj ghg

Comment: What about the other CSS that is controlling your form elements? Everything inside the form is wrapped in a div with "container" and "mt-4" classes. You could try modifying them. Also check "col-md-4" and "mb-2." All of those classes are influencing how your form is being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Contact Me</h2>
  <form method="post">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How you centered the button?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried text-align: center;?

```css
div {
  height: 900px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  test
  <br>
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  test
      <br>

  <textarea> </textarea>
    <br>
test
    <br>

<button> test </button>
</div>
```

Comment: No It doesn't center inputs